# Shortcut to create automatic tags for JS and CSS files in my project in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, css, webstorm

WebStorm is packed with nice features and shorcuts, but I'm not able to find a quick way to add JavaScript or CSS file to my HTML page.

I have a new project, I create a file index.html and a script.js (or it can be a library I downloaded or a CSS file). Now I'd like to do something like drag and drop the script.js file directly in my index.html and automatically see generated:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

At moment I'm doing it with Emmet (`script:src + <tab>`).

I know it's not much to write, but starting a new project maybe you want to include a bunch of libraries that you downloaded and it's bit annoying to do this manually. And I wanted something like I select the files I want to include and I just drop them in my html file.

So I thought WebStorm would have a smart way to do that.

Maybe this functionality is already there and I'm just not able to find it.

Comment: As far as I know you can't.. However, you can specify library's - https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#docLinks And include some neat documentation URL's so you can use that as reference on the fly while writing your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not currently supported and not yet planned for any specific future version.

In any case:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-204
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-393

Watch these tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

---

I may only suggest to create a custom [Live Template](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm) and use it to possibly speed up such insertion. Typing `s[TAB]` (where `s` is your abbreviation for such live template) is still faster than that Emmet sequence.